# If the data in the database returns more invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I created a table to be populated with `datatables`. 
If I return data from the database, I want it to take the last date of the date field and fill it with the date of the day following the existing one in the database, if it does not return data I want it to fill in with the first day of the following month the date field. I have the code as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div align="right">
     <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="alert_message"></div>
<table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Resp. de Turno</th>
      <th>Apoio</th>
      <th>Elementos ALA A</th>
      <th>Elementos ALA B</th>
      <th></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  fetch_data();

  function fetch_data()
  {
   var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "oLanguage": {
    "sProcessing": "Aguarde enquanto os dados são carregados ...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
    "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro correspondente ao criterio encontrado",
    "sInfoEmtpy": "Exibindo 0 a 0 de 0 registros",
    "sInfo": "Exibindo de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoFiltered": "",
    "sSearch": "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>",
    "oPaginate": {
       "sFirst":    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward'></span>",
       "sPrevious": "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-backward'></span>",
       "sNext":     "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward'></span>",
       "sLast":     "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward'></span>"
     }
    }, 
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
     url:"./fetchmapa",
     type:"POST"
    }
   });
  }
function novaData(d){
   var dia  = d.getDate().toString();
   dia = (dia.length == 1) ? '0'+dia : dia;
   var mes  = (d.getMonth()+1).toString();
   mes = (mes.length == 1) ? '0'+mes : mes;
   var ano = d.getFullYear();
   return dia+"-"+mes+"-"+ano;
}

  class CellDate {
    constructor(start_date) {
        this.date = start_date;
    }
    getNextDate() {
   //here the change for if condition     
   if ($('#user_data tbody tr') != null && $('#user_data tbody tr').length > 0) {
            var ultima_data = $("#user_data tbody tr:first td:first").text().trim().split("-");
            var ultimo_dia = +ultima_data[0];
            var ultimo_mes = +ultima_data[1];
            var ultimo_ano = +ultima_data[2];
            this.date.setDate(ultimo_dia);
            this.date.setMonth(ultimo_mes - 1);
            this.date.setYear(ultimo_ano);
            this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1);
            console.log('if', this.date);
        } else {
            this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() + 1);
            this.date.setDate(1);
            console.log('else', this.date);
        }
        return novaData(this.date);
    }
}

  var DateIndexer = new CellDate(new Date(Date.now()));  

 $('#add').click(function(){

   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data1">'+DateIndexer.getNextDate()+'</td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data4"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data5"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
   $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html); //<--- right here

}); 

 $(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
   var data = $('#data1').text();
   var responsavel = $('#data2').text();
   var apoio = $('#data3').text();
   var elementos = $('#data4').text();
   var elementos1 = $('#data5').text();
   if(data != '' && responsavel != '' && apoio != '' && elementos != '' && elementos1 != '')
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"./insert",
     method:"POST",
     data:{data:data, responsavel:responsavel, apoio:apoio, elementos:elementos, elementos1:elementos1},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
   else
   {
    alert("Os campos são de preencimento obrigatório!");
   }
  });
```

So if data already exists in the data table, it fills the date field with the date of the next day, but if the database table is empty and does not return data, I get the following message in the console:

> if Invalid Date

But if you remove javascript in `fetch_data ();` already works but does not show the data that already exists in the database and will always start on the first day of the next month.

I leave here the two examples. Example with problem: With `fetch_data ();` where it does not start on the first day of the next month because it does not return data [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/t0h3uq6a/1/)

Example that works: Without `fetch_data();`, but if there is data in the database it does not show it to the user [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/t0h3uq6a/).

I wanted to put the example that does not work because I want to show the data to the user, if it exists in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was if.

Then I changed this if:

```
if ($('#user_data tbody tr') != null && $('#user_data tbody tr').length > 0) {
```

for this

```
if ($('#user_data tbody tr:first td').length > 1) {
```

and solved my problem